# SDBG Debugging with GWT Plugin 4.0 on Eclipse 23-03 fails

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt, java-17

I am using SDBG chrome debugger with my Eclipse 19-09, Java8, GWT 3.0 Plugin, GWT SDK 2.10 environment. Starting debugging with - Debug as - Development mode with Jetty and later - Start SDBG debugger ...
All worked fine ...
I now want to move to Java17 using Eclips 23-03, Java17, GWT 4.0 Plugin, GWT SDK 2.10.
I started with the standard Web Application Starter Project -- all is fine. It does not show SDBG any more, but still breakpoints in Chrome etc. all is working...

With my more advanced project - Database etc. I get the following error ...

```
[WARN] Server class 'javax.sql.DataSource' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [ERROR] Found resouce but unrecognized URL format: 'jrt:/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.class'
   [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.lass.smsweb.client.rpc.FirstService.firstServer(java.lang.String[]) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/DataSource
[WARN] Server class 'javax.sql.DataSource' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [ERROR] Found resouce but unrecognized URL format: 'jrt:/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.class'
```

I found some comments on this. They all refer to the embedded Jetty solution of the GWT-plugin being outdated. Is there a way to update this or any other means to overcome the issue?